# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined at useParams - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to send params in React Router and getting below error

[image]

Code for reference
In my Route.js I have added browserRouter and Route

```
function AppRoute() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className='App-header'>

                    <Grid container justify="center" className={classes.root} spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs={3}>

                            <Paper className={classes.paper} >
                                <Link to='/'>Dashboard</Link>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper} >
                                <Link to='/create'>Create</Link>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper} >
                                <Link to="/edit/john">Edit</Link>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                        <div>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
                                <Route exact path="/create" component={Create} />
                                <Route path="/edit/:name">
                                    <Edit />
                                </Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>



                </div>
            </div>

        </BrowserRouter>


    )
}
```

Edit.js

```
function Edit() {
    const { name } = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            Name - {name}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What version of react-router-dom are you using? Is it possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue for us to live debug on?

Comment: You are using `useContext` instead of `useParams`. Thats what the error suggests.

Comment: @johnnypeter That is likely the `useParams` hook implementation. It is accessing the closest `Router`'s routing context.

Answer (score 4):

From the error you're getting, we can conclude the following:

`Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

This is happening on line 40, as you can see from your screen shot.

```
const match = useContext(Context).match
```

It means that this part of the call is returning `undefined`:

`useContext(Context) === undefined`

In other words, it means that the `Context.Provider` is not available at that point of your component tree.

You should be calling this inside a component that has been rendered by a `<Route/>`. Otherwise it will not find the `Context` and you'll get this error. Double check that.

From: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function BlogPost() {
  let { slug } = useParams();       // IT'S CALLED INSIDE BlogPost
  return <div>Now showing post {slug}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/blog/:slug">
        <BlogPost />                {/* <<< AND BlogPost IS RENDERED INSIDE A <Route/> */}
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

Comment: Thoroughly explained